# How to solve a (generalized) assignment problem?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

Assume the following initial assignment data:

```html
>>> unnamed_3.show()
+---------+-------------+-----+-------+
|   Client|     Industry|Value|Advisor|
+---------+-------------+-----+-------+
|Company A|Manufacturing| 3000|   AD 1|
|Company B|Manufacturing| 2000|   AD 1|
|Company C|      Finance| 1000|   AD 1|
|Company D|      Service| 2000|   AD 2|
|Company E|       Health| 3000|   AD 2|
|Company F|      Service| 2000|   AD 3|
|Company G|      Finance| 4000|   AD 3|
|Company H|Manufacturing| 1000|   AD 3|
+---------+-------------+-----+-------+
```

i.e. we have clients from a certain industry and with a certain value assigned to an advisor.

The goal is to harmonize the Client - Advisor assignment in a way that the number of industries per advisor gets minimized while preserving as many of the current clients as possible (e.g. "AD1" has most of his clients in Manufacturing (see counts), so keeping that industry is "preferable").

Additional constraints are that each Advisor should get 20 clients at maximum and clients should be distributed as equally as possible (in terms of value) between advisors so that total sum of value is similar between advisors. As a last constraint, clients that cannot stay with their initial advisor should get at least an industry expert as advisor (e.g. if "Company C" has to leave "AD 1" it would preferably go to "AD 3", also an expert for finance):

```html
>>> unnamed_3.groupby('Advisor','Industry').count().sort("Advisor").show()
+-------+-------------+-----+
|Advisor|     Industry|count|
+-------+-------------+-----+
|   AD 1|Manufacturing|    2|
|   AD 1|      Finance|    1|
|   AD 2|      Service|    1|
|   AD 2|       Health|    1|
|   AD 3|      Finance|    1|
|   AD 3|Manufacturing|    1|
|   AD 3|      Service|    1|
+-------+-------------+-----+
```

I hope that I formulated the problem in a way that you can understand it, but since this is my first question at stack overflow, please let me know if you need more information. Reading through other posts here, I have the feeling that this problem is closely related to a generalized assignment or binning/partitioning problem, however not fully matching any of them.

Any help on how to approach solving this problem is highly appreciated!

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**

Referring to David's answer maybe I can reformulate a bit and make things clearer here. My initial thought was that this could be done by something like a min-cost problem in a way that we connect clients nodes only with ADs from the industry sector giving cheaper weights to their initial advisors. I think this would tackle objectives 2 and 4. The client limitation per AD could also be easily fulfilled by setting the capacity of an advisor node to 20. But would I don't get in is the balancing part of the values.

Comment: This is a good start, but you’ve formulated multiple objectives that in general have to be traded off against one another: 1. Minimize industries per advisor 2. Minimize switches 3. Minimize differences in advisor total values 4. Minimize switches to non-expert advisors. I assume that 20 clients is a hard constraint, but if not 5. Minimize clients per advisor in excess of 20. By designing an optimization algorithm, we would have to decide for you (perhaps implicitly) the relative value of these things, but we really can’t.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer! I edited the formulation a bit. Because of the balancing part I was thinking of the binning problem, but probably with an additional constraint/weight for bin preference? Does that make sense? Does something like this exist?

Comment: Probably not, but you can make one yourself with mixed integer programming.